# Does hentai haram?

Tags: zina, drawing, awrah, pornography, cartoon

Hentai cartoons are not real that's why they are not mahram for anyone or they are not gonna marry anyone so they are not gonna someone else's wife.
Allah say's:One Muslim's honor/respect is deposit(amanot)for other muslim.
In this verse Allah means not to see others muslim's private parts or look at them with lust
Rasul (SA) tell us to not see anyone thigh live or dead.
Hentai are not alive creature and how can we say they are dead when they haven’t life anytime?
Rasul (SA) also say that eyes zina is see/watch but zina can only be done with alive creature.
Watching another person private parts are haram but hentai are not person or someone else's (another girl's)drawing.they are imagine.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: No.cause i have to know is my question's right or wrong. After i got my answer i will be 100 percent sure is it halal or haram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person should be chaste except with their wife and bondwoman as per (23:5-6)

> those who guard their chastity except with their wives or those ˹bondwomen˺ in their possession,for then they are free from blame. (23:5-6)
>
> The Clear Quran

The common meaning of chastity is
abstaining from extramarital, or from all, sexual intercourse by guarding private parts. However it also means not having any sexual nature or intention.

As [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chastity) also defines chastity as:

> purity in conduct and intention.

A person watching hentai / "cartoon porn" is not pure in intention so they aren't guarding themselves from sexual intention with the exception of their wife and bondwoman(s). So the person watching hentai is blameworthy.